KKT-conditions of $\min t$ such that $t-x\geq0, t+x \geq 0, x^2 -4x + 4 = 0$
I want to solve
\begin{align*}
\min_{t,x} t\\
\text{s.t. } t-x &\geq 0 \\
t+x &\geq 0 \\
x^2 -4x + 4 &= 0
\end{align*}
with the help of KKT conditions. Obviously, the solution is given by $x=t=2$, but for practice I would like to retrieve this solution via KKT.
The lagrangian is given by $L(t,x,\gamma_1, \gamma_2, \gamma_3) = t-\gamma_1 (t-x)-\gamma_2 (t+x) - \gamma_3 (x^2 - 4x + 4)$. This yields the following system of KKT conditions
\begin{align*}
1-\gamma_1 - \gamma_2 & = 0 \\
\gamma_1-\gamma_2 - \gamma_3(2x-4) &=0\\
x^2 - 4x +4 &=0 \\
t-x &\geq 0 \\
t+x &\geq 0 \\
\gamma_1(t-x)&=0\\
\gamma_2 (t+x) &= 0\\
\gamma_1, \gamma_2 &\geq 0 
\end{align*}
But if I try to plug in $x=t=2$ as a solution it follows from $\gamma_2(t+x)=0$ that $\gamma_2 = 0$, which means that because of $1-\gamma_1-\gamma_2 = 0$ we need $\gamma_1 = 1$. But then $\gamma_1-\gamma_2 -\gamma_3 (2x-4) = 1-0-0 = 1 \neq 0$. How can this be?

It looks like the Linear Independence Constraint Qualification (LICQ) is violated, that is the gradients of the active constraints at the solution are linearly dependent (which you can check).
This means the KKT conditions do not hold. However, the Fritz John conditions hold: try leaving out the objective in the definition of the Lagrangian and you should be able to find the correct solution.

But for the sufficient KKT condition of second order, do you really need LICQ?
